# Optional型(列挙型)へ値を代入

Tags: swift, swift3

```
enum Optional2<T> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    init(){
        self = .None
    }
    init(_ some: T){
        self = .Some(some)
    }
    init(nilLiteral: ()){
        self = .None
    }
}
```

let v1 : Optional2 = 10     　　　　　　　// ERROR
    let v2 : Optional2 = Optional2(10) 　　　// OK
    let v3 : Optional2 = Optional2.Some(10)  // OK
    let vnl : Optional2 = nil 　　　　　　　　// OK

上記のERRORは、本当のオプショナル型の場合、代入できますが、
上記の列挙型では、コンパイルエラーとなります。
代入演算子を作成しようと思ったのですが、実装に失敗します。
static func = (lhs: Optional2 , rhs: T)->Void{}

Comment: あなたが調べられた事実を列挙されているだけで、「質問」に当たるのが何なのか明記されていません。何をお尋ねでしょうか?

Comment: let v1 : Optional2 = 10 　　　　　　　// ERROR
を解決する方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: お尋ねになりたいことはコメントではなく、ご質問の本文中にご記載ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`let v1 : Optional2 = 10 　　　　　　　// ERROR` を解決する方法があるのでしょうか？***

ありません。

---

「`Optional`型の実態はこのようなenum型です」と言う解説をどこかで見つけられて、「それなら同じ構造を持つenum型を定義すれば、`Optional`型と同じ動作をさせることができるのか?」と言う疑問を持たれてお試しなのだと思いますが、結論は上記の通りです。

あなたが ***`ERROR`*** と示された例(が動いたとしたら)では`T`型が自動的に`Optional2<T>`型に変換されているわけですが、このような動作は本物の`Optional`型に特有のもので、同内容のenum型を定義しても同じ動作は起こりません。Swift言語の開発スタッフはこのような状況をcompiler magicと呼んでいましたが、日本語の語感に合わせて言い換えると「`Optional`型はSwiftコンパイラーから特別扱いを受けている」と言った方が良さそうです。

[Swift 4での文字列型のあり方について論じたこの文書](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md)の中では、

> `Int` is a subtype of `Optional<Int>`

と表現している部分があるのですが、もちろんSwiftの言語上の機構としてはサブタイプと言う概念はなく、コンパイラー内部の問題か、もしくはコンパイラー製作者の概念の問題で、Swift言語を使うプログラマーがデータ型間にサブタイプの関係を定義できるわけではありません。コンパイラーが`Optional`型を特別扱いして、「サブタイプ」と呼びたくなるような動作を実現しているわけです。

他にも自前の`Optional`風データ型を`if-let`などのOptional-bindingで使えるようにする方法もありません。

**`Optional`型の基本的な構造はenumだが、その様々な振る舞いはコンパイラーの特別扱い(compiler magic)によって成り立っている**

とご理解ください。

---

なお、Swiftでは代入演算子`=`はユーザ定義不可なので、代入演算子のオーバーロードによって解決することもできません。